# Wait inside if command with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to click a button on a page when it appears then wait a few seconds and click another button.

Relevant part of my code is below;

```
window.onload = function(){
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("btnx").length>0){
      document.getElementsByClassName("btnx")[0].click()
      &(document.getElementsByClassName("btny")[0].click());
  }
}
```

The problem is when it clicks the btnx it has to wait a few seconds till click btny but it click both almost at same time. Any advise about this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version of solution for this

```
window.onload = function() {
  let btnx = document.getElementsByClassName("btnx")[0];
  let btny = document.getElementsByClassName("btny")[0];

  btny.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.error("btny clicked");
  });
  btnx.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.error("btnx clicked");
    setTimeout(function() {
      btny.click();
    }, 1000);
  });

  btnx.click();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, just keep my question here with it's answer to help aynone who search in future;

```
window.onload = function(){
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("btnx").length>0){
      document.getElementsByClassName("btnx")[0].click()
      &setTimeout(function(){(document.getElementsByClassName("btny")[0].click())},3000);
  }
}
```